# Error binding to target method

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I am trying to call a static method from a helper class, of which the type is not known until runtime. I thought I had solved the problem however I am getting the following error -

"Error binding to target method."

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code? Any help would be appreciated..

```
    Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>),
                    typeof(RepositoryStringExtensions).GetMethod("GetTableName", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { objectType })) as Func<string>;

    string tableName = (string)del.DynamicInvoke(context);
```

The type "objecttype" above can be any class, "RepositoryStringExtensions" is the helper class which contains the method, the method it is trying to call is displayed below -

```
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

        return objectContext.GetTableNameByObject<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Func<DbContext, string>` instead of `Func<string>`.